# Applescript Click item in system menu bar after opening it

Tags: applescript

I can open the bluetooth dropdown menu item with this code but I don't know how to actually click on any of the items in the menu.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "ControlCenter"
    click menu bar item "Bluetooth" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

What would be a command to click on something in the open bluetooth menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following **AppleScript** code should accomplish what you are trying to achieve.  Just replace the ***"Mac Pro"*** part of the code with the name of the item you want to click.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "ControlCenter"
    click menu bar item "Bluetooth" of menu bar 1
    repeat until exists of checkbox 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click checkbox "Mac Pro" of scroll area 1 of window 1
    key code 53 -- Press escape key
end tell
```

This following **AppleScript** code will return the names of the checkboxes so you can easily know your options to use in the first code.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "ControlCenter"
    click menu bar item "Bluetooth" of menu bar 1
    repeat until exists of checkbox 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    set checkBoxNames to name of checkboxes of scroll area 1 of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: With either code I get the same error error - "System Events got an error: Can’t get process "Control Center"."

Comment: Should it not be `ControlCenter` ? That's what I used in my code above but I can't manage to fix your code by changing that part.

Comment: Well like I was saying, that doesn't fix your code. If I change them all to `ControlCenter` I just get a never ending loop which I have to break. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Already tried that, get a neverending loop. It opens the bluetooth menu ok like in my code above but then nothing else happens and it's a neverending loop...Have you not actually tried the code yourself?

Comment: Try the updated code. Yes so far every version I posted works on my system

Comment: Aha! Now that works

Comment: It doesn't close the bluetooth menu afterwards though.

Comment: Ok that's a simple way to close it. Thanks for your help, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

how to add the command to this script to open the window of the activated application in menu bar.

Now the application starts in the bar menu, but the window does not open. Can this be done?

```
tell application "System Events"
get name of every process whose name is "Scrap Paper"
if result is not {} then
    tell application "Scrap Paper"
        quit
    end tell
else
    tell application "Scrap Paper"
        activate
    end tell
end if
```

end tell